# Can't install nvidia-driver-455 (upgrade from 450 version)

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, nvidia, troubleshooting, proprietary-drivers

I have a Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon Nvidia-based (GTX 1060) system and would like to install the latest Nvidia drivers now when I noticed they're out.

However, I can't seem to be able to install it with:

```
apt-get --dry-run install nvidia-driver-455
```

which throws up the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-455 : Depends: libnvidia-extra-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-455:i386 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-455:i386 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-455:i386 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

I don't have any held packages, nor do I have any residual configurations.

---

Currently, I am running **version 450 without any problems** on kernel 5.4.0-54-generic. So, what should I do now? How to investigate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue resolved, for some reason, there remained installed a meta-package of previously installed version: `nvidia-driver-440`. Reproduced on 3 laptops already, the offending package stays the same and is blocking the Nvidia from updating.

---

After updating the OS as a whole, I rebooted, and issued:

```
apt-get purge nvidia-driver-440
```

with result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-driver-440*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 19.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 438621 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-driver-440 (450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
```

---

Now the dry run above seems to be Ok. The installation as root with:

```
apt-get --install-recommends install nvidia-driver-455
```

went smoothly and my system booted up without any problem now.

---

Visual proof (Mint's Driver Manager):

[image: Visual proof (Mint's Driver Manager)]

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04. The package issue might be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-450-server/+bug/1899522

Comment: Awesome find, solved the issue for me on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Purging the previously installed driver was the key, thanks!